# What permissions do you need to view the contents of a folder using the Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm creating a Node app from the Google Drive Quickstart guide for node.js (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs). The app just asks for permission, then downloads the contents of a folder (using a drive.files.list  query with 'parents in ${folderID}').

If I use the Quickstart project, setup the credentials and API keys as described, everything works fine. I can get the right permission (using the simple command line authorization code from the example app to generate a token), see the Drive folder AND see the files contained in the folder using drive.files.list, then download them.

But when I move from Quickstart to my actual project (which has a proper OAuth consent screen setup) everything works (I can authorize correctly via my website, and access the drive folder with the resulting token) EXCEPT the drive.files.list command returns an empty array.  No errors are generated (and I can access the name+description of the folder) but it can't see any of the files in the folder.

Once the authorization completes the code is identical other than in one case the set of credentials and auth token has been generated from the Quickstart project, the other from my actual project. Though the one from my project fails to find the files.

So I guess I must have missed some permission step, but I've no idea what.  Both projects have drive and drive.readonly permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. `drive` and `drive.readonly` of `Both projects have drive and drive.readonly permissions.` in your question means the scopes? 2. Which is your access token retrieved by the OAuth2 or the service account? 3. Can you provide your current script without your personal information?

Answer (score 0):

NM user error on my part, when I authorized the second project I used a different user that didn't have read permissions on the folder.

Its all working fine if I use the right user :)